# Convergence of the series $\sqrt[n]n-1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n=\sqrt[n]n-1$. Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hint: $$\sqrt[n]n  = e^{\frac{\log n}{n}} > 1+\frac{\log n}{n}$$

Comment: How was this taken ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @RajindaWickrama.

Comment: How is e^(ln(n)/n) > 1 + ln(n)/n

Comment: Since $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$, when $x>0$, this means that $e^x > 1+x$, since $1+x$ is just the first two terms of the series. Then $x=\frac{\log n}{n}$ to get our result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 12):

$$a_n=n^{1/n}-1= e^{\log{n}/n}-1 \sim \frac{\log{n}}{n}$$

The sum diverges by comparison with the sum of $b_n=1/n$.

Answer (score 11):

From $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to e$, we conclude 
$$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<3<n=(1+a_n)^n$$
for almost all $n$. Hence $a_n>\frac1n$ for almost all $n$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges.

*Remark:* We don't even need the introduction of $e$. The observation
$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}n^{-k}\le \sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}<1+\sum_{k=1}^ \infty 2^{1-k} =3$$
suffices for an "elementary" approach.

Comment: The "observation" is very nice, I don't think I'd seen that.

Answer (score 7):

$$\sqrt[n]{n}-1=\frac{n-1}{\sqrt[n]{n^{n-1}}+\sqrt[n]{n^{n-2}}+...+1}\geq \frac{n-1}{n\sqrt[n]{n^{n-1}}}=\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}=\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}>\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{n}$$

Now use that for all $n >2$ we have

$$\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n} \,,$$

or limit compare it to the harmonic series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fixed, ty.

Answer (score 5):

For $n\ge2$,
$$
\begin{align}
n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)
&\ge n(2^{1/n}-1)\\
&\to\log(2)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for some $N$, if $n\ge N$, then $n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)\ge\frac12$. Therefore, for $n\ge N$,
$$
\sqrt[n]{n}-1\ge\frac1{2n}
$$
Thus, the series diverges by comparison to the harmonic series.

Answer (score -1):

Note that for any $n\ge3$:
$$ n>e$$
and so,
$$ n^{1/n} > e^{1/n}$$

And since we know:
$$ e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ we can say:
$$ e^{1/n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!\;n^k} = 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2n^2}+\cdots$$
Which, for $n\in\Bbb N$, is surely larger than the truncated series $1+1/n$, and so follows the strict inequality:
$$n^{1/n} > e^{1/n} > 1 + \frac{1}{n}$$

Subtract one from both sides, yielding:
$$\sqrt[n]{n}-1 = n^{1/n} - 1>\frac1n$$

Which is true $\forall n\ge 3$. Evaluate the sum:
$$ \sum_{n\ge 3} (\sqrt[n]{n}-1) > \sum_{n\ge 3} \frac{1}{n}$$

Thus, $\sum a_n$ is larger than the divergent harmonic sum, and is divergent too.